# Retrive public facebook posts using rails, display on private website

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an internal webapp (there is no public access, the server is on our internal lan behind firewall).

In this app we have a list of "customers", and some of them have given us their facebook addresses (id or URL to their facebook page).  I would like to display inside the app a list of their most recent public facebook posts, and possibly some info on them (are they "our" friend?  How many friends to they have that sort of thing).

My company does have a facebook account, as do I personally (I'm testing using my own facebook account).

I've tried using the Koala gem, following the tutorial on their site: https://github.com/arsduo/koala, but I cannot get authenticated (it just gives me an authentication error).  I have set up an "app" on facebook under my account to do this (the app is not public).

Is this even possible to do?  I do not want to retrieve my own posts, I want to retrieve an essentially random user's posts (who may or may not be my "friend") using my facebook account as authentication.

I have managed to do this for twitter (customer provides twitter ID, company has a twitter account with an "app" on it, I use the 'twitter' gem and it all works perfectly.  I'm really struggling with facebook though...

Has anyone successfully managed to do what I'm trying to do?

Here's what I've managed so far (using Koala)
irb>

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("<token obtained from graph explorer")
@graph.get_object("me")
-> <stuff about me>
```

seems OK

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new('<app_id>', '<app_secret>') #no callback_url as there isn't one
@oauth
-> #<Koala::Facebook::OAuth:0x00000004ee1b38 @app_id="1111", @app_secret="1111", @oauth_callback_url=nil>
@oauth.get_app_access_token
-> "111114344655084|-TiiOCKSwgryrWnswdgQK5EAXfs"
```

So far, so good

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@oauth.get_app_access_token)
@graph.get_object("me")
-> Koala::Facebook::AuthenticationError: type: OAuthException, code: 2500, message: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. [HTTP 400]
```

This is the bit that I don't understand: Why can't I get a valid auth_token using my app credentials (they're not 1111 btw)?

Comment: No, that is not possible. With API v2, your app will not even be able to use “random” global user ids it gets fed – it would have to use the app-scoped user id instead, and that can only be retrieved through your app in the first place.